# Request HTML for an HTML body which loads in via AJAX

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Hi so I am currently building a webcrawler based program. Currently I've hit a road block because the response to my html request is only giving me some of the content. The rest of the content loads in my browser but does not appear when calling request(url, cb).

My guess is that this part of the html code is loaded in after via something like angularjs, because my browser shows all of the missing content (and you can see that the content that is missing is loading in after the page).

How do I work around this? Is there a way to get the html after all the elements have been added?

Thanks

Comment: Please, provide more details ...
Which API request(url, cb) is?
Include the relevant bits of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Just using request to fetch the HTML you won't be able to see what the page looks like after being rendered with all the JavaScript. I would look at phantomjs or a framework that is base on phantomjs such as http://nrabinowitz.github.io/pjscrape/. That will allow you to access the HTML after the client side JavaScript has been executed.

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm doing this on a node server. I'll probably check out one of the modules for phantomjs (seems like there is a bunch). Thanks!